# Sliding Duration with Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone please suggest, from given date how to calculate sliding duration in javascript or jquery...

I need following output..

```
- Article published 2 seconds back.
- Article publieshed 1 day back.
- Last modified 3 weeks back..
- Last mondified 1 month back...
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a plugin that does relative or friendly dates. I would recommend the [timeago jQuery plugin](http://timeago.yarp.com/) for this.

Comment: @sotware , got it now what exactly you want...this site is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

jquery animate can do many things.please go through the below api

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

you can even use interval

```
setInterval(function() //
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, this is not what I am looking... I need an algorithm that will help me calculating duration in a given format...

Comment: @software why do you need algorithm for that , you can calcuate your own time duration right

Comment: see this link ,it might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176046/how-do-smooth-slides-work-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Take the time in seconds, and divide it by the number of seconds in a year, and that's how many years. Subtract that then divide it by the number of seconds in a month, and that's how many months. Subtract that then divide it by the number of seconds in a week... etc.